# I need help figuring out how to move a row in google sheets to another sheet if there are multiple checkboxes in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have a workbook in google sheets. With multiple columns and rows, more rows will be added. I am trying to figure out how to expand to copy the entire row if there is a check in one or more of the column checkboxes to a new sheet (which there will be several).

Comment: What is the problem with the checkboxes? Can you move a row without checkboxes?

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126083/186471